# Use java.util.Map from Scala

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections, generic-collections, scala-java-interop

I need to use java-legacy code with the following method:

```
public void doit(Map <String, Object> vals) {...}
```

My Scala code:

```
var map = new java.util.HashMap[String, Any]
map += "testme" -> 'X'
doit(map)
```

yields =>

type mismatch; found : java.util.HashMap[String, Any] 
required: java.util.HashMap[java.lang.String, java.Object]

So I change it to:

```
var map = new java.util.HashMap[java.lang.String, Object]
map += "testme" -> 'X'
doit(map)
```

yields =>

type mismatch; found : Char 
required: java.lang.Object 
Note: primitive types are not implicitly converted to AnyRef.
You can safely force boxing by casting x.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].

So finally I came up with the following:

```
var map = new java.util.HashMap[java.lang.String, Object]
map += "testme" -> 'X'.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
doit(map)
```

Is there is a more concise way to deal with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's not a built in method to make it shorter, but you can write a helper method:

```
def jkv(s: String, a: Any) = s -> a.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]

map += jkv("testme",'X')
```

or use the pimp-my-library pattern to add a new operator that does this for you

```
class StringArrow(s: String) {
  def ~>(a: Any) = s -> a.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
}
implicit def string_has_arrow(s: String) = new StringArrow(s)

map += "testme" ~> 'X'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use type ascription as follows:

```
import java.lang.Character

var map = new java.util.HashMap[java.lang.String, Object]
map += "testme" -> ('X':Character)
doit(map)
```

This tells Scala that you want the `'X'` to be implicitly converted to `java.lang.Character` if it isn't one already. (It works becuase it specifies a more specific type than `Object`)

Answer (score 1):

1. Maybe you could use come implicit conversions from `scala.collection.JavaConversions._`
   It will allow you to scala mutable or immutable maps instead of `java.util.HashMap`
2. I do not know the context, but maybe you could use `"testme" -> "X"` (with String)